# Swift: Accuracy Loss Converting SVY21 to LatLon in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS app which makes an API call to extract carpark locations in SVY21 format. I then converted the SVY21 format to the WGS84 format so that I can drop pins on MapKit.

I made reference to the following github [post](https://github.com/cgcai/SVY21) and converted existing codes to Swift. The conversion was done correctly in code (validated using arbitrary northings/eastings in the Python language against my Swift version) and realised that there are some accuracy loss when I pin it on the map.

I confirmed this by using an online [calculator](http://dominoc925.blogspot.sg/p/svy21-coordinate-converter.html) and this calculator appears to yield a more accurate result.

The top left pin is a result of the online calculator while the bottom right is the conversion using the github post. The northings/eastings used here are 31045.6165, 31694.0055.

[image]

```
//Conversion SVY21 to LatLon in Swift that I converted from other 
//languages

precedencegroup PowerPrecedence { higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence }
infix operator ^^ : PowerPrecedence
func ^^ (radix: Double, power: Double) -> Double {
    return Double(pow(Double(radix), Double(power)))
}

class Convenience: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = Convenience()

    let a = 6378137.0
    let f = 1 / 298.257223563

    let oLat = 1.366666 // origin's lat in degrees
    let oLon = 103.833333 // origin's lon in degrees
    let oN = 38744.572 // false Northing
    let oE = 28001.642 // false Easting
    let k = 1.0 // scale factor

    var e2: Double!
    var e4: Double!
    var e6: Double!
    var A0: Double!
    var A2: Double!
    var A4: Double!
    var A6: Double!

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func convertSVY21(N: Double, E: Double) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {

        let b = a * (1.0 - f)
        e2 = (2.0 * f) - (f * f)
        let e4 = e2 * e2
        let e6 = e4 * e2
        A0 = 1 - (e2 / 4) - (3 * e4 / 64) - (5 * e6 / 256)
        A2 = (3 / 8) * (e2 + (e4 / 4) + (15 * e6 / 128))
        A4 = (15 / 256) * (e4 + (3 * e6 / 4))
        A6 = 35 * e6 / 3072

        let Nprime = N - oN
        let Mo = calcM(lat: oLat)
        let Mprime = Mo + (Nprime / k)
        let n = (a - b) / (a + b)
        let n2 = n * n
        let n3 = n2 * n
        let n4 = n2 * n2
        let G = a * (1 - n) * (1 - n2) * (1 + (9 * n2 / 4) + (225 * n4 / 64)) * (Double.pi / 180)
        let sigma = (Mprime * Double.pi) / (180 * G)

        let latPrimeT1 = ((3 * n / 2) - (27 * n3 / 32)) * sin(2 * sigma)
        let latPrimeT2 = ((21 * n2 / 16) - (55 * n4 / 32)) * sin(4 * sigma)
        let latPrimeT3 = (151 * n3 / 96) * sin(6 * sigma)
        let latPrimeT4 = (1097 * n4 / 512) * sin(8 * sigma)
        let latPrime = sigma + latPrimeT1 + latPrimeT2 + latPrimeT3 + latPrimeT4;

        let sinLatPrime = sin(latPrime)
        let sin2LatPrime = sinLatPrime * sinLatPrime

        let rhoPrime = calcRho(sin2Lat: sin2LatPrime)
        let vPrime = calcV(sin2Lat: sin2LatPrime)
        let psiPrime = vPrime / rhoPrime
        let psiPrime2 = psiPrime * psiPrime
        let psiPrime3 = psiPrime2 * psiPrime
        let psiPrime4 = psiPrime3 * psiPrime
        let tPrime = tan(latPrime)
        let tPrime2 = tPrime * tPrime
        let tPrime4 = tPrime2 * tPrime2
        let tPrime6 = tPrime4 * tPrime2
        let Eprime = E - oE
        let x = Eprime / (k * vPrime)
        let x2 = x * x
        let x3 = x2 * x
        let x5 = x3 * x2
        let x7 = x5 * x2

        //Compute Lat
        let latFactor = tPrime / (k * rhoPrime)
        let latTerm1 = latFactor * ((Eprime * x) / 2)
        let latTerm2 = latFactor * ((Eprime * x3) / 24) * ((-4 * psiPrime2) + (9 * psiPrime) * (1 - tPrime2) + (12 * tPrime2))
        let latTerm3 = latFactor * ((Eprime * x5) / 720) * ((8 * psiPrime4) * (11 - 24 * tPrime2) - (12 * psiPrime3) * (21 - 71 * tPrime2) + (15 * psiPrime2) * (15 - 98 * tPrime2 + 15 * tPrime4) + (180 * psiPrime) * (5 * tPrime2 - 3 * tPrime4) + 360 * tPrime4)
        let latTerm4 = latFactor * ((Eprime * x7) / 40320) * (1385 - 3633 * tPrime2 + 4095 * tPrime4 + 1575 * tPrime6)
        let lat = latPrime - latTerm1 + latTerm2 - latTerm3 + latTerm4

        // Compute Long
        let secLatPrime = 1 / cos(lat)
        let lonTerm1 = x * secLatPrime
        let lonTerm2 = ((x3 * secLatPrime) / 6) * (psiPrime + 2 * tPrime2)
        let lonTerm3 = ((x5 * secLatPrime) / 120) * ((-4 * psiPrime3) * (1 - 6 * tPrime2) + psiPrime2 * (9 - 68 * tPrime2) + 72 * psiPrime * tPrime2 + 24 * tPrime4);
        let lonTerm4 = ((x7 * secLatPrime) / 5040) * (61 + 662 * tPrime2 + 1320 * tPrime4 + 720 * tPrime6)
        let lon = (oLon * Double.pi / 180) + lonTerm1 - lonTerm2 + lonTerm3 - lonTerm4

        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat / (Double.pi / 180), longitude: lon / (Double.pi / 180))

    }

    func calcM(lat: Double) -> Double {
        let latR = lat * Double.pi / 180
        let term1 = A0 * latR
        let term2 = A2 * sin(2 * latR)
        let term3 = A4 * sin(4 * latR)
        let term4 = A6 * sin(6 * latR)
        return a * (term1 - term2 + term3 - term4)
    }

    func calcRho(sin2Lat: Double) -> Double {
        let num = a * (1.0 - e2)
        let denom = (1 - e2 * sin2Lat) ^^ (3.0 / 2.0)
        return num / denom
    }

    func calcV(sin2Lat: Double) -> Double {
        let poly = 1 - e2 * sin2Lat
        return a / poly.squareRoot()
    }
}
```

I would like to know if anyone out there has used a more reliable conversion tool to convert SVY21 to latlon so that we can drop pins onto google maps or MapKit much more accuately.

Comment: Do you want help with your code or do you want another tool to do the conversion? If it's the former your code example is confusing and not complete. For example, you have a custom operator of `^^` but no definition for it, as well as a lot of unexplained and cryptically-named methods and properties in your class.

Comment: @ColGraff I have added the portion on `^^`. The codes are not cryptically-named as it follows the mathematical-model as described in the github post I have linked in my post. Like I have asked, I would wanna find out if there are alternative tools to do the conversion.